# Android JSON API calls

Tags: java, android, json, api, callback

Im trying to figure out the best way to make a widget to pull data from a API of a company. It provides monitoring data for there service. They have a API that uses JSON calls and i need to know how to even start with the creation of this. I'm looking to build a widget and display a few different sections of data. Any recommendations, example code, etc would be extremely helpful.

Example of there API Callbacks from their URL. https://api.company.com/api/systems?callback=my_method

```
my_method(
[
  {
  "city": "Sebastopol",
  "country": "US",
  "postal_code": "95472",
  "state": "CA",
  "status": "warning",
  "system_name": "Sample Residence",
  "system_public_name": "Sample Residence",
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
  },
  {
  "city": "Petaluma",
  "country": "US",
  "postal_code": "94954",
  "state": "CA",
  "status": "normal",
  "system_name": "Sample Residence 2",
  "system_public_name": "Residential System",
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
  }
 ]
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to setup a similar type of weather web service. I used the IntentService ResultReciever pattern. I use [this](http://neilgoodman.net/2012/01/01/modern-techniques-for-implementing-rest-clients-on-android-4-0-and-below-part-2/) as my reference. Once you have it implemented, its so easy to use for any calls.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what is your issue, on parsing the JSON or on how to build the widget itself?
Android provides [good documentation on Widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html), and for parsing json you could use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes).

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't really precise, so my answer can't be. But here a few hints :

1 - First you need to download the JSON from the URL you have. To do this, you should use a class like HttpUrlConnection. You will need to do this task on a separate tread. Google has good example : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

2 - When you receive your data, it will only be a bunch of data. You need to convert this into something you can easily manipulate. Don't parse the json yourself. Instead, find a good library that will handle this for you.

3 - Then, you'll have an object will all your data, so now you can populate your view!

Good luck!